# How to generate a parameterized crystal report through clicking a button in C#?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I am new to learning Crystal Report using C#. I want to generate a report (Parameterized) by pressing a button. I can do this in VB.Net but I don't know the proper function to do this in C#.

Can any please help me resolve this problem?

Here's the VB.Net code behind the button:

```
Dim myreport as new crystalReport1
myreport.parameterFields(0).CurrentValues.AddValue(textbox1.Text);
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myreport
```

**I'm trying this code in C# but it's not working:**

```
CrystalReport1 myreport = new CrystalReport1();
myreport.parameterFields(0).CurrentValues.AddValue(textbox1.text)
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = myreport;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SetParameterValue method from crystal report.

According to this documentation http://help.sap.com/businessobject/product_guides/sapCRVS2010/en/crnet13_sp14_dg_en.pdf ( very helpful in my opinion ) , here is an example :

```
private void SettingParameters_RD(ReportDocument TestReport)
{
 string PARAMETER_FIELD_NAME = "Country";
 ArrayList countries = new ArrayList();
 countries.Add("Canada");
 countries.Add("USA");
 TestReport.SetParameterValue(PARAMETER_FIELD_NAME, countries.ToArray());
 crystalReportViewer.ReportSource = TestReport;
}
```

Written in the documentation section : "1.4.3.1.4 To set discrete parameters in a report"

You can simply use it like that in your code :

```
myreport.SetParameterValue("yourparamname",textbox1.text);
```

"yourparamname" is the name of your parameter in your crystal report report.

Regards,